# I saw in most of the website counter numbers starts from zero and reaches a specific number Is there a code in ms access vba to perform this action

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, user-interface, ms-office

I saw in most of the website counter numbers starts from zero and reaches a specific number Is there a code in ms access vba to perform this action

[image: This Gif Image Show What I want]

Comment: No, there is no code in MS Access to do what you want. You'll have to write the code yourself. For future reference, questions that contain nothing in the post body, but an image are not acceptable. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: I am a beginner and have no idea please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I already had some code, I will throw you a bone.

This would be simply incrementing a value held in a textbox on a form. I include a timer delay so you can watch the numbers change.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim Start As Double
Me.tbxHours = Null
For x = 1 To 15
    Me.tbxHours = Nz(Me.tbxHours, 0) + 1
    Start = Timer
    While Timer < Start + 0.1
        DoEvents
    Wend
Next
```

Now where you use that code and how you trigger it is for you to determine.